# Замена details и summary с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем привет, не подскажете, каким кодом можно заменить вот этот пример

```
<details>
<summary>block</summary>
text
</details>
```

используя javascript, чтоб содержимое появлялось и исчизало.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду DOM?

Comment: вообще меня интересует, как сделать так чтоб один щелчёк открывал содержимое, а другой щелчёк на этот же блок закрывал его

Comment: я думаю, то что вам нужно называется "спойлер"

Answer (score 2):

Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

```
<details onclick="this.style.display='none';">
```

Comment: эта функция только скрывает текст, а как сделать чтоб этот блок потом появился